# Table repair or creating and moving to a new one?

Tags: mysql, schema

I was altering a table adding an index to a row and that cause my entire site to bog down, so I interrupted the action.

1. What are the effects of an interruption when altering a table index in my table/database?
2. Running a table repair will fix any issue from that action?
3. What about copying all the content over a new table, with the proper index I want to set, and than rename it? Is it more efficient than a table repair?

Comment: which sort of indexing you want to implement?

Comment: I was removing a not used index, when I realised it locked the table and my site went down, after a few mins waiting for the query, I decided to kill the process.

Answer (score 0):

There are few points that you should consider before taking any action.

1. Why adding an indexing to your table caused the website to down ?
2. if you implemented indexing properly to the table without any issue than there might be some issues with the queries. may be your queries are not compatible with indexing.
3. point 3 seems meaning less if point 2 is valid.
4. Alter table allows you to perform almost every task you want to do in creating a new table.
5. Before alter tabling it is recommended to take backup so you do not have need to repair table.